# Make prettier to format like eslint

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, prettier

I see a lot of questions relating to my problem but according to what I've found, people want  eslint to ignore prettier's rules.
In my case I want prettier to have the same behavior than eslint.

I want this format

```
const bar = foo.fn()
.then(() => ...)
.then(() => ...)
.catch(() => ...);
```

in .eslintrc

```
"rules" : [ "indent": ["error", 2, { "MemberExpression": 0, "SwitchCase": 1 }] ]
```

but prettier format my code like this

```
const bar = foo.fn()
  .then(() => ...)
  .then(() => ...)
  .catch(() => ...);
```

Is it possible to make prettier to format like eslint ?

Comment: Prettier is [opinionated, on purpose](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html). You can search for "Prettier function chaining" and see that 1. a lot of people _prefer_ indenting chained functions, and 2. Prettier does not have and does not plan to add options for this.

Comment: You cannot make prettier format differently from what it does except for a few [config options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html). See https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html I have to say the format you're asking for doesn't make a lot of sense. Why would a line continuation be at the same level as the line above? Makes it hard to read

Comment: @TheJim01 thanks I didn't know that.

Comment: @JuanMendes Hard to read for me when it's indented. Chained methods are on the same level that the first one so why should they be indented ? But... it's just my opinion. Thanks anyway. I will disable prettier.

Comment: Do you work on the code alone? Most devs will have a hard time reading a continuation line that's not indented. Do you not indent your parameters when there are too many for a call and they need to go on new lines?

Comment: Parameters are indented but the closing parenthesis is not and then, chained method would be indented the same way parameters are. This doesn't make sense IMO.

Comment: I understand the reasoning for not indenting them but the way prettier does this is more common and this is actually the reason it works like that. Prettier is good for consistent style with no efforts, that's what it does. Very useful for teams. Eslint rules don't have this degree of control over formatting.

Answer (score 0):

`prettier` and `eslint --fix` have different configuration options, prettier is mostly opinionated, so it's very difficult to configure them to do the same thing, but it's possible to automatically run `eslint --fix` after prettier with [this tool](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint).

Comment: That's putting two tools to fight against each other. Let prettier do the formatting and let eslint lint the files, do not have both tools try to do the same thing

Comment: Yes, it's better to turn off the formatting related rules like [indent](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) in eslint if you use prettier too.